Integrating Jenkins with Microsoft Teams
I know there is a way to integrate Teams with Jenkins through Teams integration plugins (Incoming Webhook, for example). However, my question is: is there another way to do this integration without using these plugins?
These plugins are blocked in my office, so I'm looking for workarounds to do this integration.

AFAIK it should be possible using the Microsoft Graph API.
